# Using @Configurable to inject spring bean in JPA entity-listener

Tags: java, spring, jpa, aspectj, configurable

I try to use `@Configurable` to inject spring bean in `@PostPersist` listener.

```
@Configurable
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class BankAccountAuditListener {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@PostPersist
public void createAudit(BankAccount bankAccount){
    ...
}
}
```

Listener is called by `@EntityListeners({BankAccountAuditListener.class})`

I put this in spring configuration xml-file:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

In `createAudit(...)` function, `em` is always null.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, BankAccountAuditListener is created by Hibernate BEFORE ApplicationContext of spring is ready to use. Possibly this is the reason I can't inject there nothing.

Comment: Did you changed javaagent to the spring/aspectj one?

Comment: @marchewa, As I remember, I did. But after couple of iterations, I gave up with AspectJ approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lazily initialized bean inside your JPAEventListener class , which is initialized when the first time entity is persisted.

Then use @Configurable on lazy loaded bean.
It may not be the best solution but a quick workaround

```
 public class JPAEntityListener{

/**
* Hibernate JPA  EntityListEner is not spring managed and gets created via reflection by hibernate library while entitymanager is loaded.
* Inorder to inject business rules via Spring use lazy loaded bean  which makes use of   @Configurable 
 */
private CustomEntityListener listener;

public JPAEntityListener() {
    super();
}

@PrePersist
public void onEntityPrePersist(TransactionalEntity entity) {
    if (listener == null) {
        listener = new CustomEntityListener();
    }
    listener.onEntityPrePersist(entity);

}

@PreUpdate
public void onEntityPreUpdate(TransactionalEntity entity) {
    if (listener == null) {
        listener = new CustomEntityListener();
    }
    listener.onEntityPreUpdate(entity);
}}
```

And your lazy loaded bean class

```
 @Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    public class CustomEntityListener{

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public void onEntityPrePersist(TransactionalEntity entity) {

        //custom logic
    }
```